# Im trying to get the browser to recognize a css.php file

Tags: extensions, css

I have this file:

```
<link src="http://mysite.com/theme/skin/frontend/default/beckin/css/options.css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Which shows in the source code. Also when I click on the link in the source code it shows the css as it should. However, the browser is not using this file and it doesn't show up in the Firefox inspector.

What can I do to get the browser to use this css file?

BTW: This is for a custom extension that allows you to change the theme colors. Again, the file is working properly but the browser ignores it ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to send the right content type header for this file

```
header("Content-type: text/css", true);
```

There is also a nice post on stackoverflow that might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413107/headercontent-type-text-css-is-working-in-ff-cr-but-in-ie9-it-shows-up-as

Comment: Thanks for helping again! That's what I was missing. The small things will get you every time lol